# Which significant games quantify personality traits?

Tags: game-recommendation, roleplaying

I've designed a role-playing game that assigns numbers to a host of smaller parts of characters' personalities (e.g. Morality, Need for Attention, Regard for Comfort, Thirst for Knowledge) rather than larger parts (e.g. Intelligence, Wisdom, Charisma). Players roll against these numbers to keep the players true to their characters.

Other games apparently use similar systems, but I don't know enough about the RPG landscape to know what games could further inspire my own game.

Which games that quantify individual personality traits to a similar degree as I've described above are the most significant, either because of the game's place in gaming history or because of the game's unique innovations?

Comment: Why is this still closed?

Comment: @mxyzplk It was closed then opened after the edit long enough for the two answers then closed again. I guess some feel it's still insufficiently narrow?

Comment: Yes I had hoped to elicit comments from those who reclosed, I can guess myself.

Answer (score 4):

The most significant is probably the Pendragon RPG, which gives all PCs a set list of paired personality traits (Chaste/Lustful, Energetic/Lazy, etc.) and players roll against these passions in various situations to determine which side of their character's personality wins out.

The other one that immediately comes to mind is Ars Magica, in which characters generally have three freeform personality traits.  These can be anything the player wants with very few restrictions or requirements (combat characters should have one trait related to their bravery and hirelings should have one related to their loyalty), but they generally have little mechanical impact in the rules as written, although players are, in some editions of the game, encouraged to roll using their personality traits as a modifier if they find themselves uncertain of how their character is likely to act in a situation.

Answer (score 1):

Significant is a tricky term, but I'll go out on a limb and say that I consider the Cortex+ system to be a fairly unique system that contains an example of this kind of structure. Cortex has a unique die pool and "everything is a die" mechanic. Their marketing strategy is to apply their system to the formulaic settings of several popular TV series including Firefly, Smallville, and Leverage, which has given it a strong following. It's also one of the few systems I've seen where these character-specific personality traits are baked into the mechanics in a meaningful way.

Under Cortex+, 3 unique personality traits (called Distinctions) are detailed on the character's sheet. When the character is trying to accomplish something and acts according to those distinctions in a way that would provide an advantage, there's a bonus to their roll (under Cortex+ that means an extra d8 to their die pool).

When they act according to that Distinction but it's a disadvantage, they take a penalty (of sorts, since they add a d4 to their die pool, which can be problematic) but they earn a "Plot Point" which they can use in later situations as an advantage. It's a great mechanism for getting players to think about their actions in the context of their character's personality, i.e. role-play!

Another interesting facet of the way Cortex+ implements Distinctions is that, while they can be simple traits like Lazy, Trustworthy, etc., more often they're complex character elements that are specified by a catch-phrase, or a nickname.

For instance, from the Cortex+ Marvel Heroic RPG, Wolverine has the distinction "I'm The Best There Is At What I Do", (the rest of the quote being "...and what I do isn't very nice.") which kind of sums up the nastier, more violent side of his nature. So when he's being violent and leverages that Distinction for a d8, it calls out the fact that he's in his element, acting smoothly on instinct and years of experience.

When he's forced to participate in a press conference, and takes it as a disadvantage to earn a Plot Point, that's an incentive for the player to call attention to his discomfort and awkwardness.

Comment: I think the question wants games that use dials rather than switches for a wide variety of personality traits.

Comment: And you're not adequately covering the Cortex+ landscape here. MHR is Cortex+ Action. You're missing out entirely on Cortex+ Drama, which powers *Smallville*. C+D uses values and relationships as stats - so you might roll Duty + Ruth to see if you are able to do something that is driven by your duty to Ruth. There's more to it than that, but you get the gist.

Comment: @gomad I didn't include those because the Values aren't character specific, they're setting values, like traditional D&D Strength, Intelligence, etc. I suppose once you combine them with a relationship they're a bit more tailored, but I interpreted the OP as looking for character-specific personality qualities.  And the use of Distinctions is consistent across C+ Action, Drama, and Heroic.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah, that occurred to me. The rest of the character traits in C+ are dials, so the system rang true for me on assigning values to abstractions. Unfortunately in this specific case the personality elements are handled differently than everything else in the system. Having said that, Cortex+ is all about hacking the mechanics. There's no reason you couldn't assign a die to your Distinctions for use in the positive cases instead of just taking a flat d8.

Comment: I don't see the distinction you're making reflected in the question.